# Is this matrix equation correct?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

In this equation I have the following: $B,I$ and $A$ and I have to find the X matrix.
$$3I + B -XA = -X$$

Then I calculated:
$$3I + B = XA -X$$
$$3I + B = X(A-I)$$

Is this correct?
$$3I + B + (A-I)^{-1} = X$$

Comment: $(A-I)^{-1}$ may not exist. Take $A=I$, $B=0$,, then there is no solution.

Comment: $$A$$ and $$B$$ are defined, $$I$$ is identity matrix. Why would not $$(A-I)^-1$$ exist?

Comment: Why should $A-I$ be invertible? This is not always the case.

Comment: Check your own work: substitute the expression that you came up with for $X$ into the original equation and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last expression should replaced by $X=(3I+B) (A-I)^{-1}$, but note that, as pointed out by @Bernard, $(A-I)^{-1}$ may not exist (for instance, if $A=I$).

Comment: How do I know when to put $$(A-I)^-1$$ on the left side of $$(3I+B)$$ and when on the right side?

Comment: Dear pendermath, I am Dietrich, not Bernhard, but otherwise the answer is great:)

Comment: @AnB The factor $(A-I) $ is on the right, so if you right multiply both sides of the equation by its inverse the two factors on the right hand side will cancel out.